# How to save events in a relational database better support time-based queries on these events

Tags: database-design, relational-database

I have a system that subscribes to Kafka topics (i.e. a message bus) that publish life-cycle events.  My system needs to digest and save these events and later serve its clients (the users of this database) with time intervals information between the events.

For example, if the Kafka topic exposes the availability/status of a system (say `UP`, `DOWN`), I need to be able to query the database for:

- all the intervals where a system was `DOWN`
- how much time was this system `DOWN` in the last 7 days
- what was the unavailability (percentage) of this system in the the previous calendar month.

**Question:**

How should I save this data in the databases considering the following **constraints**:

- the events need to be saved in a relational database
- the event could theoretically be received out-of-order (they still carry the time stamp at origin)
- performance is not an issue (we will not reach the limits of Kafka, DB, or clients)
- we want to minimise code complexity and size (hence increase the maintainability of the solution)

The following example aims to facilitate the understanding of the use case. The incoming events have a source (originating system, here `system1`), a status (`UP` or `DOWN`) and a timestamp (ISO format):

**Input:**

```
system1,UP,2020-05-05T14:00:00Z
system1,DOWN,2020-05-05T16:00:00Z
system1,DOWN,2020-05-05T17:00:00Z
system1,UP,2020-05-05T20:00:00Z
```

**Outputs**

For a query of all `UP` intervals for `system1`:

```
system1,[(2020-05-05T14:00:00Z - 2020-05-05T16:00:00Z),(2020-05-05T20:00:00Z - <now>)]
```

For a query of all `DOWN` intervals for `system1`:

```
system1,[(2020-05-05T16:00:00Z - 2020-05-05T20:00:00Z)]
```

For a query on how much time `system1` was `DOWN`:

```
system1,4h
```

where:

- events with the same status can arrive multiple time (or duplicates)
- `now` represents the time of generating this result

**Researching**, one possible solution:

```
| name    | status | from                 | to                   |
------------------------------------------------------------------
| system1 | UP     | 2020-05-05T14:00:00Z | 2020-05-05T16:00:00Z |
| system1 | DOWN   | 2020-05-05T16:00:00Z | 2020-05-05T20:00:00Z |
| system1 | UP     | 2020-05-05T20:00:00Z | null                 |
```

Upon receiving a new event, you:

- update the latest event you have so far for that system (if any) adding the `to` (closing the interval) and
- start a new open-ended interval (i.e. with `to` being `null`).

But this solution does not feel the most natural way to do this and I am asking myself if there is another solution to:

- avoid multiple updates: INSERT + UPDATE on every event or INSERT + 2 UPDATES if the events comes out-of-order
- avoid and data duplication: needing 2 columns instead of one single one (considering that the time intervals are contiguous)
- simplify querying and aggregation: in this solution you would have to 
  group by `name`, sort by `from`, then eliminate consecutive duplicate `status` rows and joining the consecutive intervals with the same status.

Searching for a solution that leverages more:

- [numerical integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_integration) (as the problem can be reduced to the area between the graph and the X-axis, the time) (InfluxDB has for such data the [`integral`](https://docs.influxdata.com/flux/v0.65/stdlib/built-in/transformations/aggregates/integral/) aggregation function.)
- the numeric value behind the dates and use them in some mathematical function

Comment: @DocBrown thanks for the notification! In the mean time I’ve thrown away the safeguard of my old answer. But I really liked this question so I took the opportunity to write a new one ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### The event log

Since you need to persist the events in the database,  the first step is certainly to have a table that just takes everything that comes in.  You could call it `event_log`:

```
event_id  node     reported_state   time_code 
10304441  system1  UP               2020-05-05T14:00:00Z
10304446  system1  UP               2020-05-05T14:01:00Z
10304447  system1  DOWN             2020-05-05T14:02:00Z
10304455  system1  UP               2020-05-05T14:03:00Z
10304459  system1  UP               2020-05-05T14:04:00Z
```

This is the start of [event sourcing](https://dev.to/barryosull/event-sourcing-what-it-is-and-why-its-awesome). Instead of updating the state of your system,  you just store the events and process the events to get what you're looking for.

### Playing with the events

With this information, you could easily query for the current state of the system, by just selecting the events ordered by descending time code:  the first record in the result set is what you're looking for.  Here, for `system1`, it is `UP`:

```
10304459  system1  UP               2020-05-05T14:04:00Z
```

Finding out the start time of the current state requires requires a little more effort, since you'd have to go iteratively backwards through history to find the first record  with a different state. The one just before gives you the start date.   Here, for `system1`, it is `UP` since `2020-05-05T14:03:00Z`:

```
10304459  system1  UP               2020-05-05T14:04:00Z  <- current state
10304455  system1  UP               2020-05-05T14:03:00Z  <- odlest with that state
10304447  system1  DOWN             2020-05-05T14:02:00Z  <- before another state
```

If you have to do this frequently, it might take time. And it might make queries that combine several different tables somewhat more difficult .

### Snapshots and replay

As explained [here](https://microservices.io/patterns/data/event-sourcing.html),  to optimize these kind of process:

> In order to optimize loading, an application can periodically save a
>   snapshot of an entity’s current state. To reconstruct the current
>   state, the application finds the most recent snapshot and the events
>   that have occurred since that snapshot.

Since you said that time is not critical, you certainly can afford this kind of processing, and construct a snapshot that would look like:

```
node     cur_state last_report          start_of_state       latest_event_id
system1  UP        2020-05-05T14:04:00Z 2020-05-05T14:03:00Z 10304459
```

Now in your context, you seem less interested in the system current state and more in the system state change. The overall principle is the same but instead of maintaining a system of the system, you'd maintain periods. For building the snapshot about periods:

```
node     state from                  to                    latest_event_id
system1  UP    2020-05-05T14:03:00Z  2020-05-05T14:04:00Z  10304459
```

The period could be identified by the combination `system+from` or you could just id it sequentially. To update this table, you'd run forward the new events, ordered by time code ascending:

- if the state is the same that the last period for that system in the snapshot, you'd update the end date.
- if the state is different, you'd create a new period based on the information in the event.

This snapshot provides for all the data you need to construct the results you are looking for.

### CQRS

A related approach is [CQRS](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html). The idea is however different: the intent is to have a command part responsible of updating the data, and a query par that provides for convenient data models for querying.

In your case the writing would be event-based. Compared to my previous proposals:

- the "snapshots" would be the convenient data models for the querying
- the event log is the write store.  But each event recorded will systematically update the snapshots. So instead of using a pull approach, looking for the `latest_event_id` and reading the missing events, you'd use a push approach. The update pipeline could therefore use a flag on the event log, to say if the given event was already processed to update the database or not.
- queries would no longer use events as primary source, and would no longer have to combine reading events and using snapshots.

To be honest, when I wrote about snapshot for periods, I was already in an event-stream mind set (playing events forward), instead of a pure event sourcing mindset (playing the events backwards).

Comment: Thanks for the answer Christophe. The snapshotting and replaying from snapshots are good inputs for me. (sounds familiar with database recovery: backup + transaction logs). This helps also decoupling the saving of the incoming events from how these events need to be processed/consumed (in my case aggregated intervals).